# How to disable save password on ChromeDriver use Appium and AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I have been spending a lot of time using the common opinion about the correct capability that solves this problem.

On Java:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Or this other:

```
options.addArguments("--disable-save-password-bubble");
```

And never worked fine for me.

System configuration:

- Java: jdk1.8.0_131
- Selenium: 3.0.1
- Appium: 1.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem and not is a capability. I align the system configuration with that:

- ChromeDriver: 2.31.488763 (2.31)
- Apk (For emulator): 59.0.3071.125

It seems is important the apk version on emulator and the ChromeDriver version appium are using.

I'm using this capabilities:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions", "test-type",
            "no-default-browser-check", "ignore-certificate-errors",
            "--disable-notifications",
            "--disable-offer-store-unmasked-wallet-cards",
            "--disable-autofill-keyboard-accessory-view");
    options.addArguments("--disable-translate");
```